# Patch cable wiring/colors

Tags: layer1, cabling, cable, utp

I cut a cat5e patch cable to put a female end on the cable, but the colors for the male piece are: orange, orange/white, blue, blue/white, green, green/white, brown, brown/white. The patch cable colors are: green, light green, blue, light blue, red, pink, brown, beige. How do I make the Patch cable colors match to the Cat 5e Jack (female end)

Comment: [this search](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=cable) might answer your question though...

Comment: @PeterGreen makes a good point about what you are doing as inadvisable, but the important thing in the wiring is not the colors, it is the fact that you do not split the pairs. You must make sure that each twisted pair is correctly kept together (1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be

- green = green
- light green = white/green
- blue = blue
- light blue = white/blue
- red = orange
- pink = white/orange
- brown = brown
- beige = white/brown

You can often check the colors by looking carefully at the plug where the wires go to the pins. This will also let you check if the plug was wired to 568A or 568B so you don't inadvertantly make a crossover cable.

However I would advise against doing what you propose to do. Patchcords are made of stranded cable and wallport/patchpanel sockets are designed for solid cable. Using the wrong type of cable for the connector leads to unreliable connections. If you must have a plug on one end and a socket on the other I would suggest making up the whole assembly yourself using solid core cable and make sure that the plug is designed for solid core cable. You can get plugs for both types, again using the wrong type of plug will lead to unreliable terminations. If the vendor won't say what type of cable the plug is for don't buy.